# How can I manipulate a triangle wave, frequency in particular?

Tags: javascript, math, waveform

I'm given dynamic values that plot a triangle wave t between -1 and 1.  The starting value is 0.  I would like to manipulate these values to the following:

1. oscillate between 0 and 1
2. start at .5 (shift its phase)
3. increase its frequency by a factor of 3 or more (by 2 is still too slow)

Using the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave) and [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleWave.html) entries on Triangle Waves, I'm able to partially accomplish this using formulas similar to this:

[image: Triangle wave with amplitude 2, period 4]

But having control over freq in particular has got me stuck.

For example, `(t+1)/2` takes care of 1 and 2 above, but #3 (freq) is only doubled...  How would I triple or quadruple the frequency?

Comment: Not sure why I'm getting voted down, would love some insight on how to make this question better... I've easily spent a few days wrestling with this stuff now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me use the JS syntax since we don't have MathJAX here on SO.
I assume you are familiar with this equation

```
y = abs( 2*x % 2 - 1)
```

[image: Triangular signal with frequency 1, amplitude 1, centered around the y-axis]

The values are not causal:

- The modulus is necessary to create a periodic pattern. A value of 2 is necessary so that the maximum value the function reaches before starting a new cycle is 2 (actually 2 is a Least Upper Bound, but that's fine).
- A maximum amplitude of 2 is necessary so that after subtracting 1, the function image ranges in [-1, 1).
- Subtracting 1 is necessary so that with an absolute value the function get flipped for negative value, assuming the triangular shape and ranging in [0, 1]
- Multiplying by 2 is necessary so that *x* runs twice as faster, making the function complete an emi-cycle at 0.5 (thus a cycle completes in 1 unit).

This function than has amplitude one and frequency one, assuming the x-axis is time (if it's space then it has wave-length of 1 unit of space).

Scaling and offsetting the function is easy (thanks to the amplitude of unitary value):

```
y = abs( 2*x % 2 - 1) * scale - offset
```

For example `y = abs( 2*x % 2 - 1) * 3 - 1.5`

[image: Graph of the function with amplitude 3 and offset 1.5]

Note that this function still has frequency 1.
To change the frequency it suffices to make *x* run faster by multiplying it

```
y = abs( 2*freq*x % 2 - 1) * scale - offset
```

to add a phase we just need to add an offset to *x*

```
y = abs( (2*freq*x + phase) % 2 - 1) * scale - offset
```

The phase is in the range [0, 2] where 0 is 0% and 2 is 100%.

Here an example of a wave with amplitude 1, offset 1.5, frequency 1/3 and phase 1 (50%):

[image: Wave with amplitude 1, offset 1.5, frequency 1/3 and phase 1 (50%)]

---

For visual reference, a better typed version of the final formula is

[image: y = abs( (2*freq*x + phase) % 2 - 1) * scale - offset]

Comment: Thanks so much for the in-depth explanation!  `y = abs( (2*freq*x + phase) % 2 - 1) * scale - offset` was exactly what I needed, yet couldn't find on my own.  I'm not sure why my question is still being voted down, but your answer is sure to help others.  Rock!